# How to sort a linked list using priority queue

Tags: java, generics, linked-list, priority-queue

I have been trying to write a method to take in a linked list and sort it using a priority queue

I have no clue how to write this code I understand how a priority queue is supposed to work but I don't know how to put that into code

```
Override
    public void priorityEnqueue(AnyType x) {
       if (isEmpty()){      
    back = front = new ListNode<>(x);
    }
    {
    back=back.next = new ListNode<>(x);
        }
    }
```

I am aware of the fact that this only returns the list as is without sorting it and that is exactly what I need help with

Comment: please don't attach images, these are harder to use on all levels for reading your code than just actually copy&pasting your code and using the code formatting button `{}` atop of the question editor.

Comment: Also, what needs work *all over your code* is that you seem to be using a modern editor, but not its code indentation feature. Do that, before replacing your images with actual code in the question. Nobody has ever regretted properly indenting one's code - it uncovers bugs and logical problems faster than any other method I'm aware of. Improperly indented code is literally the first sign that I look for in students when they claim they're "experienced programmers" but really aren't.

Comment: Also, you should always tag your question with the programming language it's about. Not only does that give your code correct syntax highlighting, it also leads experts your way.

Comment: Now, back to the focus of your question:

Comment: **How** do you know that this snippet is the "only code that needs work"? I find that highly unlikely, because otherwise you'd solved the issue at hand already. But: you came to that conclusion based on some (probably very good!) analysis; we don't know that analysis, but it would greatly help any potential answer if you told us. Otherwise, your question is just "debug my code; I help you not at all with that", and such questions are explicitly off-topic, because they're just much work for the answerer with little chance of success for the asker.

Answer (score -1):

This is the answer I figured it out

```
@Override
   public void priorityEnqueue(AnyType x) {
   ListNode<AnyType> node = new ListNode<>(x);
   
   if(front == null){
       front = node;
            back = node;
    }
    else{     
    if(front.element.compareTo(x) > 0){
        node.next = front;
            front = node;
    }
else{  
    ListNode<AnyType> current = front; 
        while(current.next != null && current.next.element.compareTo(x) < 0)
            current = current.next;
               node.next = current.next; 
               current.next = node; 
     if(node.next == null)
        back = node;
           }
       }
   }
```